# Issue with ajax success and error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have posts which can be upvoted, User can upvote only once for a post. I wanted to change dynamically the value of the votes when they hit the upvote button so I used ajax. Here is my code :

**Controller**

```
  def like
    user = params[:user_id]
    idee = params[:idee_id]
    if Vote.exists?(:user_id => user, :idee_id => idee)
     redirect_to :back, :notice => "Vous avez déjà voté pour cette idée"
    else 
      Vote.create({ idee_id: idee, user_id: user})
      redirect_to :back, :notice => "Merci d'avoir voté"
    end
  end
```

**View**

```
<% if @idee.votes.count  == 0 %>
      <div class="upvote col-lg-2"> 
       <div class="heart black hidden-xs">
         <p class="like"><%= @idee.votes.count %></p>
          <%= link_to "up", {controller: "vote", action: "like", user_id: @current_user, idee_id: @idee}, :method => :post, :remote => true, :class => "upvote-link" %>
       </div>
      </div>  
      <% else %>
      <div class="upvote col-lg-2">
        <div class="heart hidden-xs">
         <p class="like"><%= @idee.votes.count %></p>
          <%= link_to "up", {controller: "vote", action: "like", user_id: @current_user, idee_id: @idee}, :method => :post, :remote => true, :class => "upvote-link" %>
        </div>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

**JS**

```
$('.upvote-link')
        .bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
            $('.like').html(parseInt($('.like').html(), 10) + 1)
            if ($(".heart").hasClass("black")) {
                $(".heart").removeClass("black");
            }
        })
        .bind('ajax:error', function(evt, xhr, status, error) {
        });
```

The problem is that when I click like 10 times, the view will show 10 votes, but the count in the db is 1. I believe that the ajax:error isn't take into consideration and it always increment the view

**EDIT**

**Association**

Idee

`has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
 belongs_to :user`

Vote

```
belongs_to :idee
belongs_to :user
```

User

```
  has_many :idees, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're making an ajax call the controller shouldn't be doing any redirects, as that only makes sense for html requests.  You should have a `respond_to` block for each type of request you want to handle.

Both of the redirects (the one for when a vote is created and when it isn't) will be treated as being a success by the ajax.  Generally, whether a new vote is created or not, if your controller responds by sending some data back with a success code, then ajax will treat it as a success.  You'll only get the error code back if your server hits an exception, or deliberately returns an error code, which isn't the right way to deal with this in my opinion.

A much better way to deal with this is to have the controller send back the html for an updated vote button, and the ajax replace the existing vote button with that code.  Them you don't have to encode your application logic, formatting, styling etc into your javascript.  In fact, you don't even need any javascript at all besides that generated by the remote link_to

I would do this like so:

```
#in view
<%= render :partial => "idees/vote_button", :locals => {:user => @current_user, idee => @idee}

#new partial, app/views/idees/vote_button
<% if @user.votes.find_by_idee_id(@idee.id) %>
  <div class="heart hidden-xs">
    <p class="like"><%= @idee.votes.count %></p>
    <%# html for a disabled vote button, ie not actually a form, but just a greyed out graphic or something %>
  </div>   
<% else %>
  <div class="heart black hidden-xs">
    <p class="like"><%= @idee.votes.count %></p>
    <%= link_to "up", {controller: "vote", action: "like", }, :method => :get, :remote => true, :class => "upvote-link" %>
  </div>    
<% end %>

#controller
def like
  if @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id]) && @idee = Idee.find_by_id(params[:idee_id])
    if Vote.exists?(:user_id => @user.id, :idee_id => @idee.id)
      @notice = "Vous avez déjà voté pour cette idée"
    else 
      Vote.create({ idee_id: @idee.id, user_id: @user.id})
      @created = true
      @notice = "Merci d'avoir voté"
    end
  else
    @notice = "<french for \"Sorry, we couldn't find that user or idee\">"
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do 
      redirect_to :back, :notice => @notice     
    end
    format.js do 
      if @created
        render :partial => "idees/vote_button", :locals => {:user => @user, idee => @idee}
      end
      #do something with "notice"?  update a div with the contents?  put it in an alert?
    end
  end
end    

#javascript
#don't need any -it's all done by the remote link and the format.js block in the controller
```

Comment: Thank you Max for your answer, but I get an error (in the console) when I hit the button and then the view isn't updated. votes is undefined, do you have any idea ?

Comment: What's the error?  You should see it in your log/server output.

Comment: I assumed that was set up as an association.  Can you please add your relevant associations as an edit to your question?

Comment: I have edited the question. The error message is 'ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `votes' for "4":String)'
4 is the id of the idee

Comment: Ah, sorry - i was setting @user to params[:user_id] whereas it should have been `@user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])`.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: OK, updated the controller section which had a couple of other bugs.

Comment: Well, that still doesn't work. I'm going to let the normal version, without ajax, for the moment and look at for the ajax later. But I really appreciate your help